EF Core customize scaffolding without deriving from internal classes
Entity Framework Core Customize Scaffolding describes a process for customizing the entities created when scaffolding an existing database using Entity Framework Core. This we've done successfully up through EF Core 6.
However, it uses classes in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal namespace. Since they are for internal use only, they're subject to change in future versions.
Migrating to EF Core 8, the interface to the classes has changed, and we're going to need to rework our code.
Before doing that, is there any way to customize the DbContext and entities created, without deriving from the internal classes CSharpDbContextGenerator/CSharpEntityTypeGenerator?

EF Core Power Tools !

Since EF 7 you can use the Custom Reverse Engineering Templates which are based on the T4 templates.
First install the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Templates package for dotnet new:
dotnet new install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Templates

Then add templates to the project:
dotnet new ef-templates

Which will add 2 files to the project - DbContext.t4 and EntityType.t4:

The DbContext.t4 template is used to scaffold a DbContext class for the database, and the EntityType.t4 template is used to scaffold entity type classes for each table and view in the database.

Then modify them accordingly to match your generation patterns.
